# How to use case_when for a list

Tags: r

I have a list as follows:

```
   tryout<- list(c("stomach:biopsy", ",colon:biopsy", ",stomach:biopsy"), 
        character(0), character(0), "oesophagus:biopsy", character(0), 
        character(0))
```

I want to replace the term `"stomach:biopsy"` with the number 1. I want to do this with  `case_when` from `dplyr`

I have tried:

```
lapply(tryout, function(x) 
    x %>% 
           mutate(group = case_when( 
             grepl("stomach:biopsy",x ) ~ 1
           )))
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

So how can I run the case_when for a nested list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are lots of blanks elements, we can create an index that checks whether there are atleast one element.  Subset the `list` and `replace` based on the pattern

```
i1 <- lengths(tryout) > 0 
tryout[i1] <-  lapply(tryout[i1], function(x) replace(x, x == 'stomach:biopsy', 1))
```

If it is a partial match, then use `grep` as in the OP's post

```
tryout[i1] <-  lapply(tryout[i1], function(x) 
           replace(x, grep('stomach:biopsy', x), 1))
```

#### Update

Based on the comments from OP, there are multiple patterns to be replaced.  In that case, it is better to create a key/val dataset or named vector and then do a `left_join/match` etc.  In this case, as it is a partial match, it would be better to make use of `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)
# create a key/val tibble
d1 <- tibble(key = c("stomach:biopsy", "colon:biopsy", 
             "oesophagus:biopsy"), val = 1:3)

# loop through the list elements having at least one element
# left join with the key/val dataset
# pull the column of 'val'
# update the list elements
tryout[i1] <- map(tryout[i1], ~ 
                tibble(key = .x) %>%
                  regex_left_join(d1) %>%
                  pull(val))
```

Comment: So I guess if I want to replace several phrases this would do too but wouldn't case_when statements be more efficient?

Comment: @SebastianZeki. If there are lots of phrases, then create a key/value dataset and do a simple join or match to replace it.  Would be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

tryout <- 
  tibble(
    var = list(
      c("stomach:biopsy", ",colon:biopsy", ",stomach:biopsy"), 
      character(0),
      character(0),
      "oesophagus:biopsy",
      character(0), 
      character(0))
  )

tryout %>%
  mutate(var = map(var, ~case_when(
    .x == 'stomach:biopsy' ~ '1',
    TRUE ~ .x
  ))) %>%
  pull(var)
```